# CIFS issues - Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, Windows 2012R2 Storage Spaces

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to Linux and I was hoping someone could help me out here with an issue I'm experiencing with connections to my file server.

I have a NAS in my home network that is running Windows Server 2012R2 and is serving files via SMB shares (ReFS / storage spaces underlying). Everything seems to work fine sometimes, but other times - much more often than not of late - these shares become inaccessible and seem to lock up a lot of my desktop environment... namely anything that tries to interact with the file system. It only happens from my linux desktop. I have a couple other Windows 10 boxes and they are able to access the shares without issue.

This is not the first time I've had this issue. At one point I was quite frustrated with it and couldn't resolve it so I ended up taking Windows out of the occasion and converting my NAS to FreeNAS (CIFS). I didn't end up liking it, but the mounts never gave me issues with locking up. I've since gone back to Windows as my needs require it and I missed the AD integration / ease of management. It wasn't long before the locking issue came back though.

I'm mounting these shares with cifs-utils via /etc/fstab like so:

```
//<ip>/<share> /mnt/media cifs auto,_netdev,rw,noperm,credentials=<<path to creds>>,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,sec=ntlm 0 0
//<ip>/<share> /mnt/storage cifs auto,_netdev,rw,noperm,credentials=<<path to creds>>,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I've tried doing some research and have not had any luck finding anyone else with the same issue. The closest I've found is people mentioning the gnome network manager potentially causing a similar issue, which is why I put the _netdev argument on there - but it didn't help.

I'm thinking that maybe when I installed the network-manager-openvpn-gnome package the issue started occuring. I use my VPN connection quite a bit though so getting rid of it really isn't an option.

As I mentioned, I'm a newb when it comes to Linux stuff (standard windows convert - trying to get better!) so I don't even know where to look for logs that would give me information as to what is causing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm out of ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those who face this kind problem, it is recommended to diagnose them using smbclient first. Because smbclient seems implement more background negotiation stuff than CIFS mount client. 
 i.e.

```
smbclient //<ip>/<share> -I <ip> -U <username>
```

If you are able to got into the windows folder, that's mean you are having hard time with CIFS mount options, it can be ANYTHING.

The next step is fire up sniffer like WIRESHARK. Then capture the package of smbclient, then compare to your CIFS mount.  Then try command line mount before you edit /etc/fstab. e.g.

```
sudo mount -vvv -t cifs //<ip>/<share> /mnt/media -o credentials=<<path to creds>>,noserverino,sec=ntlmssp
```

as in here, because I notice the packget sniffer show me error from server refuse my inode, thus I am getting lucky by trying out `noserverino`. And the host server is a Windows 10 Pro.